# Existence of Total Order Compatible with Partial Order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory, order-theory

I was reading Stong's Cobordism Theory, the following lemma to be precise.[image]
In the proof, he gives a total order on the set of non-dyadic partitions with the given partial order After some research, I came to know that we can always give a total order to any set courtesy [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem). But could not find anything about the existence of a Total order, Compatible with a given Partial order.

As I am not really an expert on Discrete Mathematics.

Any hints, suggestions will be really helpful.

regards

Comment: I think what you want is the [Szpilrajn extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szpilrajn_extension_theorem).

Comment: Thank you so much, that really helped @amrsa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be a partially ordered set; we want to find a total order $\lt$ which extends the given partial order. This is trivial if $P$ is finite; suppose $P$ is infinite.

Let $\mathcal F$ be the set of all finite subsets of $P$. For each set $F\in\mathcal F$ choose a total order $\lt_F$ of $F$ which is compatible with the given partial order.

Let $\mathcal U$ be an ultrafilter on $\mathcal F$ with the property that $\{F\in\mathcal F:x\in F\}\in\mathcal U$ for each point $x\in P$.

Finally, for $x,y\in P$, define
$$x\lt y\iff\{F\in\mathcal F:x\lt_F y\}\in\mathcal U.$$
It is easy to see that $\lt$ is a total order extending the given partial order.